# In a LR circuit, Why do the current rate of increase decreases with time?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

In a LR circuit, the current rate of increase decreases with time until it reaches zero eventually and that is when the current become steady. My question is why the current rate of increase decreases with time? At t=0, the current is equal zero and the induced emf work in an opposite sense of polarity to that's of the source, my question is why this initial current instantaneous rate of increase doesn't stay at the same value instead of diminishing with time? And I don't think it is because the magnetic flux rate of increase decreases with time, cause what I understand is that the magnetic flux rate of increase is the result of the current rate of increase and not the other way around. And if it is indeed the other away around and the decrease of magnetic flux rate of increase is the reason, then What makes the magnetic flux rate of increase decreases with time?

Comment: You need to. include more details on the LR circuit.

Comment: Please, consider adding a picture of your circuit and the initial conditions, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do the current rate of increase decreases with time?

Because as the current increases, the resistor drops more voltage. KVL tells us that the sum of the resistor and the inductor voltages is equal to the source voltage, increasing the resistor voltage means there is less voltage across the inductor, and therefore $dI/dt$ is reduced.